# Use RDBMS to reduce memory consumption?

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite, postgresql, memory

In my Visual C++ application, I want to allocate a lot of objects, which will use up all available memory in the system. To solve this problem, I decide to store the objects in database. I just have 3 candidates: MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite. But don’t know which one is more appropriate.

What I need is:

1. Store objects in the database instead of memory.
2. Fast to find the objects via a key.
3. Light-weight so the RDBMS will not require a lot of system resources, including both the memory and disk spaces.
4. No server required.
5. Easy to deploy.

Which one should be best for my needs? Of course, if you have any other better alternatives, then just tell me.

SQLite provides a detailed doc how when it should be used. But MySQL and PostgreSQL does not so it is a little difficult to choose as I am not familiar with these two. Thanks.

Comment: Modern databases does lot of *caching*, meaning they store data *in memory*. Using a database is almost never a solution from memory exhaustion, quite the opposite. After you think about that a little more, the only one database you list that satisfies all requirements (especially number 4) is SQLite. However, if you just want a key-data store there are many other alternatives.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg A modern database that stores data on disk will definitely use less memory than storing everything in memory, for non-trivial amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SQLite. It doesn't require a service and is cross platform. It is easy to deploy and is light-weight. It supports transaction. It's in the public domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions:

1. Store objects in the database instead of memory.

   Any database can do this, that's the definition of a database.
2. Fast to find the objects via a key.

   Also standard functionality, if you can't find your data, what's the point of using a database.
3. Light-weight so the RDBMS will not require a lot of system
   resources, including both the memory and disk spaces.

   That's mostly in your hands, bad queries generate a lot of overhead. No matter what brand of database (or software language) you use.
4. No server required.

   Do you mean "hardware" or "client-server model" ? Both MySQL and PostgreSQL are services in a client-server model. SQLite works best for a single client.
5. Easy to deploy.

   All 3 databases are easy to deploy, but SQLite is the easiest one. It's not a server like the others.

It looks like SQLite is the best fit, but also check your other requirements, the ones you didn't mention: performance, reliability, backup, failover, etc. etc. And do you needs an RDBMS for this kind of work? A C++ object in memory is very different from a bunch of records in a couple of databases that can be accessed by using SQL.